# Button.Text.Contains Double Enter

Tags: vb.net, button, contains

I need to check my button to see if it has multiple lines of text if it does **NOT** then I need to enter that information into the textbox.

So far I have:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click, Button5.Click, Button4.Click, Button3.Click, Button2.Click, Button1.Click

Dim btn = DirectCast(sender, Button)
Dim btntext = btn.Text
If btntext.Contains(vbcrlf)=false then
   Rtextbox.Text += btntext
End If
End Sub
```

However this only checks if there is one line break, I need to check for two

**EDIT** The line breaks are not in a row, there is text in between

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count them:

```
Dim btntext = btn.Text
Dim numberOfLines = (btntext.length - btntext.Replace(vbCrLf, "").Length) \ vbCrLf.Length

if (numberOfLines > 1) then ....
```

Answer (score 1):

If the text contains more than one Newline, then the location of the first and last Newlines will be different.

```
Sub Button1Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click 
    Dim btn = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    If btn.Text.IndexOf(vbCrLf) = btn.Text.LastIndexOf(vbCrLf) Then Rtextbox.Text += btn.Text
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check for two consecutive newline characters specifically, you can just change your code to this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click, Button5.Click, Button4.Click, Button3.Click, Button2.Click, Button1.Click   
    Dim btn = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    Dim btntext = btn.Text
    If btntext.Contains(vbcrlf & vbcrlf)=false then
       Rtextbox.Text += btntext
    End If
End Sub
```

Note the change from `vbcrlf` to `vbcrlf & vbcrlf`.

If you want to check for 2 or more newline characters you can do this with a regular expression that counts the number of new line characters:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click, Button5.Click, Button4.Click, Button3.Click, Button2.Click, Button1.Click   
    Dim btn = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    Dim btntext = btn.Text
    If New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("\n").Matches(btntext).Count >= 2 then
       Rtextbox.Text += btntext
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What about `line1\r\nline2\r\nline3`

Comment: I didn't want to type `"line1" & vbcrlf & "line2" & vbcrlf & "line3"` to indicate non-consecutive crlfs

Comment: @AlexK. then use a `System.Text.StringBuilder`, I dunno.

Comment: @roryap I think the problem is the OP didn't state if he or she is looking for two consecutive newlines, or any string that contains more than one newline. Your answer works for the first case but not the second.